# Mysql match exact set of result in a single table

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble with generating result set. This is what my 'user_roles' table looks like,

```
 id            user_id       role_id
  1              1            1
  2              1            2
  3              2            1
  4              3            1
  5              3            2
  6              3            3

 ...             ...            ...
```

I want this result where user has exact both roles i:e 1 and 2, I do not want those user having roles other than 1,2.

```
 id            user_id       role_id
  1              1            1
  2              1            2
 ...             ...            ...
```

I have tried so far,

```
SELECT
*
FROM
`user_roles`
WHERE `role_id` IN (1,2)
HAVING COUNT(id) = 2
```

But, it returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could aggregate by `user_id` and use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user_roles`
WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT user_id
                    FROM `user_roles`
                    GROUP BY user_id
                    HAVING SUM(role_id IN (1,2)) = 2
                       AND SUM(role_id NOT IN (1,2)) = 0);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo*`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/426073)**</kbd>

<sup>*SQLFiddle does not respond so SQL Server equivalent</sup>

Note:

I assumed that `user_id, role_id` are unique and not null.

Comment: It returns exact result set. Thank you so much, much appreciated.

Comment: It took Time: 0.034s

Answer (score 3):

#### Why your query doesn't work

`HAVING` applies after `GROUP BY` and your query doesn't have one. When the query contains `HAVING` or [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) but it doesn't contain the `GROUP BY` clause, a single group containing all the selected rows is created.

Before applying `HAVING`, your query selects the rows having `id` in `1..5` (i.e. 5 rows). A single group is created from them, `COUNT(id)` returns `5` and the `HAVING` condition doesn't match. That's why the query doesn't return anything.

In order to correctly count the number of roles of each user it needs to group the records by `user_id`:

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `user_roles`
WHERE `role_id` IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY `user_id`
HAVING COUNT(`id`) = 2
```

This way, the `WHERE` clause selects the user having the roles `1` or `2` (but it ignores other roles), the `GROUP BY` clause allows the function `COUNT(id)` to count the number of selected roles for each user and the `HAVING` clause keeps only those users having both roles (`1` and `2`). The `SELECT` clause is not allowed to contain `*` because for the columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause, MySQL is free to pick any value it finds in the corresponding column and it may return different results on different executions of the query.

**However, the query above doesn't return the values you want. It completely ignore the roles that are not `1` or `2` and it will return the user having `user_id = 3`.**

---

#### A query that works

This query returns the users having only the roles `1` and `2` is:

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `user_roles`
GROUP BY `user_id`
HAVING COUNT(`role_id`) = 2 AND GROUP_CONCAT(`role_id`) = '1,2'
```

The condition `COUNT(role_id) = 2` is not needed. In theory it should improve the execution speed (because counting works faster that string concatenation) but in real life it might have no impact whatsoever. The MySQL engine knows better.

**Update**

@martin-schneider asks in a comment:

> is the order of `GROUP_CONCAT(role_id)` deterministic? or could it be that the result is '2,1'?

It's a very good question that has the answer in the [documentation of function `GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> To sort values in the result, use the `ORDER BY` clause. To sort in reverse order, add the `DESC` (descending) keyword to the name of the column you are sorting by in the `ORDER BY` clause. The default is ascending order; this may be specified explicitly using the `ASC` keyword.

The complete query is:

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `user_roles`
GROUP BY `user_id`
HAVING COUNT(`role_id`) = 2
  AND GROUP_CONCAT(`role_id` ORDER BY `role_id` ASC SEPARATOR ',') = '1,2'
```

I omitted `ORDER BY` and `SEPARATOR` because their default values (sort ascending by the values that are concatenated and use comma as separator) are good for our needs in this query.

#### Important to notice

There is a limit for the length of the value computed by the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function. Its result is truncated to the value stored in the system variable [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) whose default value is `1024`.

This value can be increased using the `SET` MySQL statement before running the query:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1000000
```

However, for this particular query the default limit of `1024` characters is more than enough.

Comment: is the order of `GROUP_CONCAT(role_id)` deterministic? or could it be that the result is '2,1'?

Comment: It took Time: 0.020s, Awesome.